# AIMLbot Input string was not in a correct format. C#

Tags: c#, aiml

I try to make an artificial engine with AIMLbot in C#, but when I say the first word the program breaks and I get the following error:

> Exception User-Unhandled System.FormatException: 'Input string was not
>   in a correct format'

at the line

```
Result result = bot.Chat(request);
```

The code with the error:

```
private void Rec(object s, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    string speech = e.Result.Text;
    //richTextBox1.Text = "You: " + speech + Environment.Newline;

    richTextBox1.AppendText("You: " + speech + Environment.Newline);
    Request request = new Request(speech, user, bot);
    Result result = bot.Chat(request);

    richTextBox1.AppendText("AIDA" + result.RawOutput + Environment.Newline + Environment.Newline);
}
```

I really need some help :))

Answer (score 0):

Your error

> Input string was not in a correct format

Tells you that you have something expecting a string but you are not passing it in a string.  The exact line that this is failing on tells you that it is

```
request
```

that is not a string when you are passing into `bot.Chat(request)`

You have declared it as a Request thus it is not a string, however it may be null so if you put a break point on that line, debug and step through the code you can inspect the value of request and see what it is.

Hope this helps